# Sync users table data from 6 different mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have 6 mysql databases with the same table names like users_table with the field email_address, now I want to get email_address from all 6 db those are missing in any one database table.

Please provide me some suggestion on the same.

Comment: is there anyone with solution for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one selects all emails that are missing in one of the databases and points out in which database they are present.

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(db_Name) AS emailIsOnlyIn FROM (
   SELECT 'db1' as db_Name, email FROM db1.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db2' as db_Name, email FROM db2.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db3' as db_Name, email FROM db3.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db4' as db_Name, email FROM db4.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db5' as db_Name, email FROM db5.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db6' as db_Name, email FROM db6.yourTable
) subquery_alias
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT db_name) < 6;
```

If you want to know in which database an email is missing it's a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
   SELECT email FROM db1.yourTable
   UNION 
   SELECT email FROM db2.yourTable
   UNION 
   SELECT email FROM db3.yourTable
   UNION 
   SELECT email FROM db4.yourTable
   UNION
   SELECT email FROM db5.yourTable
   UNION 
   SELECT email FROM db6.yourTable
) sq,
    (    SELECT 'db1' as db_Name2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'db2' as db_Name2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'db3' as db_Name2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'db4' as db_Name2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'db5' as db_Name2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'db6' as db_Name2
   )dummy
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (
   SELECT 'db1' as db_Name, email FROM db1.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db2' as db_Name, email FROM db2.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db3' as db_Name, email FROM db3.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db4' as db_Name, email FROM db4.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db5' as db_Name, email FROM db5.yourTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'db6' as db_Name, email FROM db6.yourTable
   ) subquery_alias
 WHERE sq.email = subquery_alias.email AND subquery_alias.db_Name = dummy.db_Name2
)
```

- here's an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1746b/13/0) which demonstrates proof of concept

Comment: Thanks, it's working same as I wanted, you are the man, thank again.

Comment: @vipinbairagi You're welcome. The usual way to say thanks here is to accept the answer by clicking the check left to the answer :)

Comment: Hi, is there any way to optimize this query? as it's taking too much time to execute when there is 2K records in each DB table.

Comment: Have a try with an index on email and db_name columns. If that doesn't help, it would be better if you posted a new question including result of `explain select...` of the query and the table structure.